# Can Dishonored run on Windows 8?

Tags: steam, dishonored, windows-8

Can Dishonored run on Windows 8 or do I need to use Windows 7? It was never confirmed in the specs.

Comment: see [this meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/how-should-we-handle-windows-8-compatibility-questions)

Answer (score 3):

It runs fine on windows 8 pro 64 bit for me.
Just make sure you have the latest video drivers installed that support windows 8

Comment: Thanks, I heard there were some comparability issues but I guess not.